# Rails test: test image_tag on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, view, rspec

I'm writing the view tests and I want to test an image:

```
<%= image_tag "icon.png", class: "img-responsive" %>
```

So I made this test, but is not working:

```
it 'app logo' do
  render
  assert_select 'img.img-responsive[src=?]', asset_path('icon.png')
end
```

It works if I use the following, but I think that it is not the right way of doing it:

```
it 'app logo' do
  render
  assert_select 'img.img-responsive[src=?]', '/assets/icon.png'
end
```

What could be the problem?
Is this the correct why to test it with rspec?

Comment: What's the error trace?

Comment: it just fails the test and checking at the rendered page it renders this: `<img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/icon-e2b3082e88fb48115dd034ffa716fbfc.png" alt="Icon">`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it the method in the question is the correct or incorrect way but you can try the following:

```
expect(response.body).to include('icon.png')
expect(response.body).to have_css(".img-responsive")
```

Comment: this ways works, but it doesn't test the element's type or class

Comment: You are right, I have edited my answer to include a test for the class of the element.

Comment: but that code don't test that the image have that class. I could be in any other element rendered

Answer (score 0):

Try this using capybara:

```
page.should have_selector(:xpath, XPATH_OF_THE_IMAGE_ELEMENT)
```

Comment: With capybara i could do `it { expect(response.body).to have_selector('img.img-responsive') }` But i can't check the src or at least i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can inspect element (img tag) from browser and then right click on element code. Click on 'Copy Xpath'. Use this xpath in the above mentioned code

Comment: but still can't check is the the image is the correct one